# iOS build fails with invalid signature: 0x80014 while unzipping the iOS device build zip file from the server (containing the .plist and .ipa files)

Tags: ios, npm, visual-studio-cordova

When I try to build my app with the device flag from visual studio I get back this message. I cant wrap my head around what the problem is.

Has wrong signature something with the certificates to do? Or is the zip file I get back bad?

```
------ Downloading completed build files from http://*:3000/build/273/download to D:\*\bld\iOS\Debug
1>  ------ Done downloading the build outputs to D:\*\bld\iOS\Debug
1>  ------ Extracting the build outputs to D:\*\bin\iOS\Debug
1>  Archive:  D:\*\bld\iOS\Debug\273.zip
1>    inflating: BlankCordovaApp2.plist
1>  
1>  C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\q\q.js:126
1>                      throw e;
1>                            ^
1>EXEC : error : Error from downloading build outputs to D:\*\bin\iOS\Debug: Error: invalid signature: 0x80014
1>      at Extract.<anonymous> (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\lib\remoteBuild.js:228:25)
1>      at Extract.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
1>      at Parse.<anonymous> (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\unzip\lib\extract.js:28:10)
1>      at Parse.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
1>      at C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\unzip\lib\parse.js:64:12
1>      at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)
1>C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(99,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" build --platform "iOS" --configuration "Debug" --projectDir . --projectName "BlankCordovaApp2" --language "en-US" --buildServerUrl "192.168.0.19:3000" --buildTarget "iOSLocalDevice"" exited with code 8.
```

Comment: It seems there might be some issue with `unzip` npm package. Can you check whether you are able to unzip the downloaded zip using File Explorer Extract All. If you are able to unzip file which contains *.ipa & *.plist, then you deploy the package to device using iTunes manually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Abhishek-MSFT! Yes, there is no problem to extract the files. Have you got any ideas how I can get rid of the error message? I have tried to update all npm packages, clean cache and repaired VS upd 3. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okey, to resolve this issue I did replace the unzip npm package with decompress-zip. Then I modified the source code in vs-mda-remote C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\lib\remoteBuild.js to use decompress-zip instead. Now everything works as it should!

Probably unzip is not as robust as decompress-zip to handle zip files.

Thanks @Abhishek-MSFT for pointing me in the right direction!

Step by step solution:

1. navigate to C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda
2. Open package.json and add "decompress-zip": "0.0.8" to dependencies.
3. run npm install in current directory
4. navigate to lib and open remoteBuild.js
5. Add "DecompressZip = require('decompress-zip')" to the vars chain in the top
6. then modify the function unzipBuildFiles(zipFile, toDir) somewhere around line 220 to look like below

   ```
   function unzipBuildFiles(zipFile, toDir) {

       console.info(res.getString('ExtractingRemoteBuild', toDir));
       util.createDirectoryIfNecessary(toDir);

       var deferred = Q.defer();

       var unzipper = new DecompressZip(zipFile);

       unzipper.on('error', function (err) {
           deferred.reject(new Error(res.getString('ErrorDownloadingRemoteBuild', toDir, err)));
       });

       unzipper.on('extract', function (log) {
           console.info(res.getString('DoneExtractingRemoteBuild', toDir));
           fs.unlink(zipFile, function (err) {
               if (err) {
                   console.info(res.getString('FailedToDeleteRemoteZip', zipFile));
               }
               deferred.resolve();
           });
       });

       unzipper.extract({
           path: toDir,
           filter: function (file) {
               return file.type !== "SymbolicLink";
           }
       });

       return deferred.promise;
   }
   ```

   Now try to build and this will resolve the issue with wrong signature

Comment: Received the below error:  TypeError: Object function DecompressZip(filename) {
      events.EventEmitter.call(this);  
      this.filename = filename;
      this.stats = null;     this.fd = null;
      this.chunkSize = 1024 * 1024; // Buffer up to 1Mb at a time     // When we need a resource, we should check if there is a promise for it
      // already and use that. If the promise is already fulfilled we don't do the
      // async work again and we get to queue up dependant tasks.
      this._p = {}; // _p instead of _promises because it is a lot easier to read
  } has no method 'Extract'

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, still it is not resolving 
For this issue i just navigated into \bld\iOS\Debug folder for ipa files.
Unzip manually folder named the respective ipa files.
Double click on ipa file to get into iTunes and installed it.

Comment: @gobi please have a look on my updated answer. I hope that it will resolve your problem as well

Comment: Is there any way to repair the software without modifying the source?